# calculating expanding mean for all columns in df pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My df looks like this:

```
    cat1     cat2     x1     x2     x3      x4      x5      x6   . . .
0    str     str    float  float   float  float   float   float  . . .
1    str     str    float  float   float  float   float   float  . . .
.     .       .       .      .       .       .       .       .   . . .
.     .       .       .      .       .       .       .       .   . . .
```

I've tried this:

```
df = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).apply(pd.expanding_mean)
```

but that gives me a

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

The only strings are in the groupby. 
This works fine but isn't what I need:

```
df = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).mean()
```

Comment: can you not just index the columns: `df[df.columns[2:]].apply(pd.expanding_mean)`

Comment: I don't know if it is ok for your purposes, but try `df = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).transform(pd.expanding_mean)`

Comment: @ EdChum, no the calculations depend on values from both columns

Comment: @Fiabetto transform made my first couple columns disappear but it looks like the rest of the data might be correct

Comment: @Fiabetto so the values ARE correct. the two cats are year and name. why does transform work and is there a way to get it to work without having to add the columns back in after the fact?

Comment: @user2891518 that's a good point, despite it works there is something tricky in `transform`...

Comment: Perhaps a slight improvement on @Fiabetto's answer:  `df.iloc[:,2:] = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).transform(pd.expanding_mean)` which will preserve first 2 columns and over-write the others (assuming that is what you are asking for?).  @Fiabetto may want to write up as an answer as this seems to be a decent solution to the problem.

Comment: Re transform vs apply:  generally speaking you use transform to keep the same number of rows when the function would otherwise reduce the number of rows.  It's not clear to me why it is needed here as expanding_mean should not be reducing anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks also to other users' efforts, the following might be a solution:

```
df.iloc[:,2:] = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).transform(pd.expanding_mean)
```

Which preserves the first two columns.